# Logistic Regression and optimal parameters w

Tags: machine-learning, logistic-regression

When I learn Logistic Regression, we use negative log likelihood to optimize the parameters w for us.

SO the loss function(negative log likelihood) is L(w).

There is an assertion that:   **the magnitude of the optimal w can go to infinity when the training samples are linearly seperable.**

I get very confused:
1. what does the magnitude of optimal w mean?
2. Could you explain why w can go infinity?

Answer (score 2):

1. It is the norm (euclidean, for example) what is usually understood as a magnitude of a vector.
2. Assume that we do binary classification and classes are linearly separable. That means
   that there exists `w'` such that `(x1, w') ≥ 0` for `x1` from one class and `(x2, w') < 0` otherwise. Then consider `z = a w'` for some positive `a`. It's clear that `(x1, z) ≥ 0` and `(x2, z) < 0` (we can multiply equations for `w'` by `a` and use linearity of dot product), so as you can see there are separating hyperplanes (`z`s) of unbounded norm (magnitude).

That's why one should add regularization term.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
This is fundamental characteristic of the log function.

consider:

```
                  log(x), where x spans (0,1)
```

Range of values log(x) can take:

```
                         is (-Inf, 0)
```

---

More specifically to your question - 
Log likelihood is given by: ( see image )

```
  l(w)  =   y * log( h(x)) + (1 - y) * log (1 - h(x) )

  where,

      h(x) is a sigmoid function parameters by w:
               h(x)  =  ( 1 + exp{-wx} )^-1
```

For simplicity consider the case of a training example where y = 1, 
the equation becomes :

likelihood (l) :

```
            = y * log ( h(x) );

            =     log ( h(x) )
```

h(x) in logistic regression maybe represented by the sigmoid function.
it has a range (0,1)

Hence, 
range of (l):

```
           (log (0), log(1) )  = (-Inf, 0)

           (l) spans the range (-Inf, 0)
```

---

The above simplification only considered the (y = 1) case. If you consider the entire log likelihood function (i.e for y=1 & y=0), you will see a inverted bowl shaped cost function. Hence there is a optimum weight that will maximize log likelihood (l) or minimize negative log likelihood (-l)